# Subtract one day from a particular date using MomentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I get the second week of 2018 like this using moment.js

```
 var date =moment([2018]).isoWeek(2).startOf('isoWeek').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I need to get the date previous to the this date; i.e. the date previous to 
08-01-2018

Comment: Please search before asking. You can literally Google your question title to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment substract method:

```
.subtract(1, 'days');
```

Comment: If i pass 0 what should happen?